# How to find the help on the special keywords such as &optional in emacs lisp

Tags: elisp

Some of the arguments in the emacs lisp function contains the keyword &optional where to find the documentation of those keywords. I tried searching using describe-function and describe-variable without sucess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reference to `&optional` in the elisp manual of my Emacs24 (dev version).

Look in info <kbd>C-h i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> elisp <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> functions <kbd>RET</kbd> go to the second entry `Lambda Expressions` then `Argument List`.

`&optional`is described in the third paragraph.

And it can be found [online here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Argument-List.html).

Comment: Or, once you're at the elisp manual (`C-h i m elisp RET`), you can check the index (`I &optional RET`), or use incremental search (`C-s &optional` with repeated `C-s` to find successive matches. There are other related functions too. As usual, `C-h m` within an info node will shows you the major mode help and list all its keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

The "&-keywords" are `&optional` (this is an argument that is either provided or defaults to `nil`) and `&rest` (this must be the last argument, its value is a list of all 'remaining' arguments to the function, once all required and optional arguments have been 'consumed').

A fuller explanation can be found in the emacs lisp manual, as per @seki's answer.